# Global short cut key for a QPushButton

Tags: c++, qt, qkeysequence

How could I register a global short cut key for a certain QPushButton?
Especially when the QPushButton is not a direct child of the main window.

Comment: Do you mean global shortcut for whole OS(you should catch this shortcut if user doesn't work with your window)?

Comment: Yes. For example, how could I register the windows button for certain application and prevent the windows start menu from popping out?

Comment: I know how to create global shortcut for something like Ctrl + Something, but single Windows key is not a shortcut, I catched windows key pressing a few minutes ago with global keyboard low-level hook, it works good, but I don't know how to disable Start menu appearing

Answer (score 0):

You mean

[QKeySequence](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.6/qkeysequence.html)

[QShortcut](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.6/qshortcut.html)

classes? Or do you just need something more powerful?

Answer (score 0):

Usually you create a [`QAction`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaction.html#details) and you add it to a menu or a toolbar. You can set a shortcut, icon, tooltip etc, this is not exactly a QPushButton but it's pretty close and it is easy to link your action to any slot of your convenience.

But if you just want to capture a shortcut or a key to steal it from the OS, *MasterAler* is right, go for [`QKeySequence`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qkeysequence.html#details) or [`QShortcut`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qshortcut.html#details).